# How to use variable as table name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

```
BEGIN
   _table_name := 'mytable';

   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _table_name (
     id integer NOT NULL,
     name character varying,
     active boolean
   ) ON COMMIT DROP';

-- logic here

RETURN QUERY SELECT table1.id, table1.name FROM _table_name AS table1;
END;
```

I have simplified my problem. I'm trying to use a variable as the table name.

I know you can do things like `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = _id` where `_id` is a declared varaible.

I know I can do this `EXECUTE`, but then I have a query like:
`INSERT INTO table2 (id) SELECT id FROM unnest(_ids) as id` where _ids is an array.

Anyway to solve problem 1 with using a variable as table name? and problem 2, using `unnest` inside `EXECUTE`?

So the problem is that the queries take `_table_name` as a literal table name, it doesn't look like it's using 'mytable' as the table name instead.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I already read that. My argument was that how come you can use variables in literal queries like in the example with `_id` vs the create table example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dynamically changing the table name (i.e. via a variable) then you will need to use `EXECUTE`. You can use this with arrays and unnest, as long as you cast the arrays to/from a `TEXT` representation.

```
DECLARE 
    _ids INT[] = ARRAY[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
    _table_name TEXT = 'mytable';
BEGIN 
  EXECUTE
    'INSERT INTO ' || QUOTE_IDENT( _table_name ) || ' (id)
     SELECT id
     FROM unnest( ' || QUOTE_LITERAL( _ids::TEXT ) || '::INT[] ) AS id';
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have been told about [dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in plpgsql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). You build the query string dynamically including invariable **code** and **identifiers**.

But do ***not*** concatenate **values**. Use the **`USING`** clause instead:

```
DECLARE 
   _ids INT[] = ARRAY[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
   _table_name TEXT = 'mytable';
BEGIN 
   EXECUTE
    'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(_table_name) || ' (id)
     SELECT * FROM unnest($1)'
   USING ids;
END;
```

Avoids error-prone casting back and forth.

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)